# Esconder imagem de um botão

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic

tenho um ngfor de botões com determinadas imagens, mas quero que incialmente essa imagens apareçam com a cor preta e somente ao clicar na imagem apareca a imagem. Como ficaria minha class mostra_imagem no css?

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let img of array.image" >
        <button id="botao" (click)="mostraImagem(img)">
          <img src="{{img}}" class="mostra_imagem">
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: ng-show ou o ng-toggle não te ajudaria?

Comment: não daria porque a ideia é carregar todos os botões com essa imagem e ocultar a imagem do botão entende? e em algum momento vou fazer ela aparecer novamente então não seria retirar e sim ocultar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IONIC 2:**

Coloca um ID na imagem:

```
<ion-content>
 <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let img of array.image" >
      <button id="botao" (click)="mostraImagem(img)">
        <img src="{{img}}" class="mostra_imagem" #minha_imagem>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

faz as importações:

```
import {ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('minha_imagem') elem:ElementRef;
```

no constructor:

```
private rd: Renderer2
```

na funçao:

```
mostrarImagem(img): void {
// dentro fica assim:
  this.rd.addClass(this.elem.nativeElement, "mostra_imagem"); // adiciona a classe
}
```

1. [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/y8iFYDjtaXCIaoaWN0pB?p=preview;)
2. [FONTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302063/ionic-2-how-to-add-class-from-controller)